# Determine if b is in the span of the other given vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the vector $b$ is the span of the other given vector. If so, write $b$ as a linear combination of $a$
a=$\begin{bmatrix}
3\\ 5\end{bmatrix}$

b=$\begin{bmatrix}
9\\ -15\end{bmatrix}$

I am a bit lost on how to approach this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any scalar $c$ such that $$c\;\begin{pmatrix} 3\\5\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 9\\ -15\end{pmatrix}\;\;?$$

That is, is it possible that both of the following equations hold: $$3c = 9\;\text{ AND }\;5c = -15$$ for the some fixed scalar $c$?

If not, then $b$ is not in the span of $a$.

---

Note the difference in outcome if $\,b\,$ happened to be $\;\begin{pmatrix} 9\\15\end{pmatrix}$. Then, indeed, $b = 3a$.

Comment: No there cannot. Thus b is not in the span of vector a.

Comment: Exactly! Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Well I understand that for a vector to be in the span of another then you can take the linear combination of the vectors each being multiplied by a scaler. Correct?

Comment: Correct. In this case, you have only one vector $a$, so need exactly one scalar $c$. In this case, that amounts to whether $b$ is a multiple of $a$, which it is not.

Comment: Ok got it! The simplicity I guess actually threw me off. :(

Comment: Now how about the case for two vectors a and another vector b? I should just take the sum of the linear combination of the vectors and set them equal to b. Correct?

Comment: Yes: You end up getting a system of equations, and if you haven't learned yet, you can use matrices to check whether there exists constants $c_1\vec{a_1} + c_2\vec{a_2} = \vec{b}$.

Comment: Got it! Woop woop!